# Remove duplicates in array (Not all)

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

How can I remove duplicates for this array.
I need to specific what Productnames that not must be duplicted.
It's only the "Test1" that not must be duplicated. Test2 may be duplicated.

Thanks.

```
Array
( 
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [Status] => OK 
        [Productname] => test1 
    ) 

[1] => Array 
         ( 
        [Status] => OK 
        [Productname] => test1
      ) 

  [2] => Array 
         ( 
    [Status] => OK 
    [Productname] => test2
      ) 

  [3] => Array 
         ( 
    [Status] => OK 
    [Productname] => test2
      ) 

)
```

**EDIT**

-My output-

It remove the Status and Productname

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [OK] => 1 [test1] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [OK] => 1 [test2] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [OK] => 1 [test2] => 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
$a = array(
    array('Status' => 'OK', 'Productname' => 'test1'), 
    array('Status' => 'OK', 'Productname' => 'test1'),
    array('Status' => 'OK', 'Productname' => 'test2'),
    array('Status' => 'OK', 'Productname' => 'test2')
);

$uniq_name = 'test1';
$key = 'Productname';
$b = array();
$uniq = array();

array_walk($a, function($a) use (&$b,$key,$uniq_name,&$uniq) {
    $name = $a[$key];
    if ($name !== $uniq_name || !$b[$name]++) $uniq[] = $a; 
});
print_r($uniq);
```

[working example](https://eval.in/144551)

`array_walk` goes through the input array one element at a time. The array `$b` is used to keep a counter of how many entries with the same `Productname` are in the output array `$uniq`. Elements are only added to `$uniq` if the `Productname` is **not** the one that should be unique, or if no elements with the same name have already been added.

**edit**:
While the above approach works, it is a bit hacky. You might consider it a bit cleaner to make your meaning more explicit, using something like:

```
array_walk($a, function($a) use (&$b,$key,$uniq_name,&$uniq) {
    $name = $a[$key];   
    if ($name !== $uniq_name || !isset($b[$name])) $uniq[] = $a;
    $b[$name] = 1;
});
```

[working example](https://eval.in/144552)

Rather than rely on the fact that if `$b[$name]` isn't set, it evaluates to `false`, you can use `isset()`.

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Status] => OK [Productname] => test1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [Status] => OK [Productname] => test2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [Status] => OK [Productname] => test2 ) )
```

Comment: Nice. Can you please make a code where both test1 and test2 not will be duplicates. And test3 must be duplicated.

Comment: Your code removing something from the array so the productname and status not are there I think it converts it from multidimensional array to normal array

Comment: Please don't edit my answer to add your own details. My answer is valid for your original question. If you change your question, I can adapt my answer.

Comment: Could you please post a code where it removes test1 and test2 duplicates and not test3 duplicates. So I can define two uniq names.

Comment: No, not until you edit your question to clearly show what you want. When you have done that, feel free to let me know. Until then, please stop sending me messages.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
        array('status'=>'OK','Productname'=>'test1'),
        array('status'=>'OK','Productname'=>'test1'),
        array('status'=>'OK','Productname'=>'test2'),
        array('status'=>'OK','Productname'=>'test2')
    );

print_r(array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR));
```

and [here](http://3v4l.org/NCB7L#v529) is the fiddle for your help.

The output of the above is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => OK
            [Productname] => test1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => OK
            [Productname] => test2
        )

)
```

Comment: array_unique is also removing the test2 duplicates. I only want it to remove the test1 duplicates.